# Using AJAX to submit form to two locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need some help. I'm using AJAX to submit my form to one location and then to another location. once its posted to that second location it sends an email with php to whoever I want, but i cant seem to get it to work. Can some one please help.

Here is my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input#submit').submit(function(event){
            var dataString = $('form :input').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://www.domain.com/sendmail.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                    $('p#message').text('SUCCESS!!!');
                },
                error: function(result){
                    $('p#hint').text('there was an error');
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some algorithms already in place, you will have problems on the server side handling the data. You may want to prepare the data and than stringify it to JSON. I would also keep the ajax functionality in its own function an use the `promise` feature. That way you can also use it for other calls within your script.

**ajax function with deferred**

```
function ajaxsend(data, url) {

    var deferred = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
    });
    return deferred.promise();

}
```

**form data handling and preparation**

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $('form').serializeArray();
    var formobject = {};

    // transform data to prepare for JSON
    $(formdata).each(function (e) {
        formobject[formdata[e].name] = formdata[e].value;
    });

    var data = {
        json: JSON.stringify(formobject)
    };

    var url = 'http://www.domain.com/sendmail.php';
    var url2 = 'some_other.php';

    ajaxsend(data, url).done(function (response) {
        // handle returned results
        console.log(response);
    }

    ajaxsend(data, url2).done(function (response) {
        // handle returned results
        console.log(response);
    }

}
```

At the server side you receive the value with:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

Then you can access your data with the fieldnames of your form. For instance ..

```
$data -> firstname;
```

You can send a response from the php file:

```
if(success == true) {
  $result = array("success" => true , "message" => "form submitted");
  echo json_encode($result);
}

if(success == false) {
  $result = array("success" => false , "message" => "an error occured");
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

At the javascript side you can catch the response values

```
console.log(response.success);
console.log(response.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference:

```
       $('form').submit(function(event){ // 'input#submit' is a button and cannot be "submited", just clicked
            var dataString = $(this).serialize(); // suffisant
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://www.domain.com/sendmail.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                    $('p#message').text('SUCCESS!!!');
                    return true; // trigger the form default action
                },
                error: function(result){
                    $('p#hint').text('there was an error');
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: thank you i realized that when i posted this. there is another action on the form that doesn't go anywhere when i hit the submit button. how do i get that one to work?

Comment: sorry but i don't understand

Comment: <form action="domain2.php" method="post">
<input name="name"/>
<input name="email"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

How do i get the form to complete this action as well as the ajax action?

Comment: see the (better) @Daniel response.

Comment: @user2402492 - if you use the `event.preventDefault()` command in jQuery, you prevent the form from submitting.